# How to check that file is not opened by another process?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I check, that file is not opened by another process?

Now I use **OS.File.move(...)** to move file back and forth:

```
var promise = OS.File.move(filePath, newFilePath);

promise.then(
    function onFulfilled(){
        OS.File.move(newFilePath, filePath);

        // Success
    },
    function onRejected(){
        // Fail. Ask user to close another application
    }
);
```

But this solution is weird. Is there any other way to perform this check?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. And you have a great solution there! You probably want to stick with that method. I never though of this way, I'll have to test it on mac/*nix to make sure, but it sounds like it should work, as if a file is in use it should not be moveable. I struggled with this a couple years ago.

Also rather then move, you can do a rename. Renaming is the same thing as `OS.File.move` but into the same directory.

The non-trick way requires js-ctypes:

On Windows you can do this `OS.File.open` and if that fails then it is open. If it succeeds make sure to `.close()` as it was not in use by other. This won't work on mac/*nix as `open` can open anything.

On mac/*nix you have to use `open` then `fcntl` then `close` via js-ctypes as I did here: https://github.com/Noitidart/Profilist/blob/219f225643828a000c60d01ea212505bb0817ff5/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L1313

You can see in this same function, in the above block, if it's Windows I do the `OS.File.open`. My code here is bit more complicated because I also get the `pid` of the process that has it open.

I defined all this in the `ostypes` lib - https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes - you can import that and use it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Just open it yourself. If it can be opened, you can do what you want to do with it. If not, ask the operator to close and after his confirmation that it is closed, retry

Comment: This will work only for Windows. In Linux/Unix it won't. See my solution below.